How to learn standard values in RF engineering
I see a lot of questions in this stackexchange about how to become Isaac Newton in 6 easy lessons.  While that might be my ambition, it's not my question.
I am retired from a long career in Electronic Warfare (EW) in the US Navy, followed by decades in communications in two-way radio engineering, cellular system technical management, etc, and then a later career in IT in system administration followed by decades in software development.
In my Navy career, though I have no formal mathematics training beyond high-school geometry, they did teach enough trigonometry and basic calculus in my EW training that, at that time, I at least was able to perform well enough in that role.  But that limited training, 50 years ago, is the extent of my mathematics training.  After that, and after doing electronic design, including limited RF design, I pretty much forgot everything I knew about RF design and the limited mathematics I understood so long ago.
Now I am retired and I want to go back into electronics and RF design.  I'm a 55-year licensed amateur radio (ham radio) operator and now that I am retired I want to get more involved in the technical side of the hobby - things I once did very well but long forgot.  I want to design and build a frequency-synthesizer-based SDR, with digital filtering demod, etc.
The point of the history is that I've some reasonable background for this decades ago but I'm too old now to start college - and my health is too unreliable to do that anyway, so I am stuck with self-teaching online.
So to my question; when I see formulas for designing RF circuits, there are all kinds of Greek symbols that I don't know, for instance, jω.  I know the j operator but not the ω. I have searched for days and I find some definitions where it is defined as frequency, others where it is defined as 2πfC, or as bandwidth, or other things that tell me there may not be a standard definition - and yet, most of the RF design books I am reading offer no definition or explanation for ω or φ or many other Greek symbols.  I also don't find definitions for those in any of my college-level math books from College Algebra through Stewart's Calculus.  In the RF Design books, the symbols show up in complex formulas from the very first pages but with the assumption that I already know what it means in context, or in any context for that matter.
So my question is, then, where are such things taught and where will I find them, and all the common things like them?  What books, in RF design or in Mathematics, did I miss or am I missing?  And I don't necessarily mean which title by which author, but what class or topic am I missing?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It's not clear what books you're finding these formulas in. If they're technical manuals for particular components, they may assume you have the knowledge of an electrical engineer. In any case, this is not something that is defined in mathematics.

Crawford's Frequency Synthesizer Design, for one; that is the book I am trying to study the most right now.

I think the symbols you are referring to are specific to electrical engineering, not mathematics.  As such, you might be better asking this queston on electronics.stackexchange.com.

At the end of Chapter 1, Crawford says explicitly, use this book as a supplement to a good basic reference. That is, read the other book first and then use this book to get a little more of the story. I would take the author at his word on this point. If you can't get the reference books he recommends, maybe electronics.stackexchange.com can suggest alternatives.
